# Remote Desktop, alt tab issues

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I'm using remote desktop on a 43" 4k monitor. I don't use my remote session fullscreen, only a part of the screen is used.

I would like to configure the setup in the way that windows key + tab works on the local machine, while alt + tab works on my terminal server. Is there any way to do this?

Software used:

- Windows 10 (both local and remote)
- Remote desktop windows store app

Answer (score 0):

Solution I found:

When I don't pass my shortcuts to the terminal server, I can use the alternative keyboard shortcuts of Remote Desktop Connection.